# Warning on basic printf program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, printf, warnings

So everything was working properly and one day i just opened vs code to continue working on my projects and i got this error:

```
implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I included the <stdio.h> library i uninstalled and reinstalled all the c extensions even reinstalled the vs code itself and the warning is still there even on the hello world program.
If you have any suggestions please help me out

I wanted to compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("fffff");

return 0;
}
```

Without any warnings

Comment: Is this an intellisense warning in VSCode, or do you get the warning when you compile?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sv14rTcP7 <- cannot reproduce

Comment: @dbush i get the warning when i compile, also when i write code instead of auto completing with printf it suggests printf_S

Comment: You could try compiling from the command line, if it's the compiler itself or VS Code that is doing it.

Comment: Then please copy and past the exact command used to compile and the exact compiler output.

Comment: This is one of those cases where the more details the better (and there's a glaring lack of them)

Comment: I used the top right compile-run button to build and run. I get this when i compile: note: include '<stdio.h>' or provide a declaration of 'printf'
    1 | #include <stdio.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h> although I have include the stdio library as you can see in the code above

Comment: Also i get the warning i mentioned in the problems tab in vs code: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: @ikegami sorry for the lack of the details im just new to this and im trying to collect as much as i can

Comment: Does it really suggest `printf_S` with an uppercase `S`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry printf_s

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of macros you could try. If you put `#define _CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES` as the first line in your program - above _all_ `#include`s, does that make a difference?

Comment: @TedLyngmo now it doesnt even compile

Comment: @Georgetzoi What actual compiler are you using?  And are you compiling as C or C++?  Given [your compiler is pushing `printf_s()` on you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty,_and_doubt#Microsoft), is this a Microsoft compiler?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess so because I use Visual Code Studio as my editor and i have installed the C/C++, C/C++ compile run, C/C++ extension pack extensions

Comment: _"now it doesnt even compile"_ - I can't magically guess what error you got.

Comment: You've given us pieces of the compiler output, but not the whole thing.  Please *copy and paste* the *entire* output of the compiler into *the question*.

Comment: @dbush Sorry for my terrible explanation. Should i copy paste from the problems tab in VS code or from something else?

Comment: @Georgetzoi Are you compiling as C or C++?

Comment: C as far as i know and i get the warning only for the first printf of the program. If the program has for example 5 printf functions the warning will appear only on the first one

Comment: If you tell us the compiler command-line, we'll be in a position to tell whether it's compiling C or C++. The mention of `printf_s` suggests C++.